# Set(int index, E element) method linked list

Tags: java, replace, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Struggling with my set-method that shall replace the element at the specified index in the list with the specified element and return the element previously at the specified index. I am not sure everything is correct but my question is what I shall return in the end?

```
    public E set(int index, E element) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if (index >= size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Node newNode = new Node(element);
    Node tempNode = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
        tempNode = tempNode.getmNextNode();
    }
    newNode.setmNextNode(tempNode.getmNextNode().getmNextNode());
    tempNode.setmNextNode(newNode);
    return ;
}
```

My Node class:

```
 public class Node<E> {
private E mElement;
private Node<E> mNextNode;

Node(E data) {

    this.setmElement(data);
}
public E getmElement() {
    return this.mElement;
}
public void setmElement(E element) {
    this.mElement = element;
}
public Node<E> getmNextNode()
{
    return this.mNextNode;
}
public void setmNextNode(Node<E> node)
{
    this.mNextNode = node;
}}
```

Comment: You need to store off the node you're replacing, before you replace it, and return it afterwards.

Comment: Do you *have* to return?

Comment: If you're just setting the value at that index in the list, why are you creating a new node? Why not just update the value in the existing node and return the old value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to create new Node (e.g newNode in your code). You can go to the desired Node with specified index, after that you can replace Element.

```
public E set(int index, E element) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    if (index >= size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    int i = 0;
    Node tempNode = head;

    while (i < index)
    {
        tempNode = tempNode.getmNextNode();
        i++;
    }

    E previousElement = tempNode.getmElement();
    tempNode.setmElement(element);

    return previousElement;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!